# Can I send 2 governors in one attack?

Tags: realm-of-empires

What is the effect of sending more than 1 governor? Is decrease in approval dependent on the number of governors sent in the attack?

Answer (score 2):

There actually is ONE benefit from sending more than a single governor in each attack (although it is almost never actually worth it).

The way the battle system works is when you send one governor (or one unit of any kind) and half (or more) of your total troops from that attack die, the single governor will also be killed.

However, if you send more than one governor (let us pretend you sent 2), and let us say that you lose 600 out of 1000 knights in that attack, one of your governors will die, but the other will actually survive to get the hit, so if you think a player might be trying to dodge and snipe you but is low on troops, it is in fact sometimes a good idea to send more than one gov with your attacks in case they are only able to partially kill your attack wave, but can do enough damage to kill a single governor.

Of course, that being said, this is really only true in very rare circumstances and only when you are very comfortable with the basics of attacking and ready to move onto more advanced strategies.

Answer (score 1):

You should only send 1 governor with any one attack. Sending more than 1 does not give you any benefits.